# Unable to pass data to vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass the **name** from **data** to my settingTemplate.
However, I have not been able to make it work. Could anyone advice how I should approach this? I am new to Vue.

**app.js**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        settingTemplate
    },
    data: {
        name: 'Elon'
    }
})
```

**setting-template.js**

```
const settingTemplate = {
template:
 `<div class="d-flex flex-column text-md-center">
    <div class="p-2">
      <b-btn id="popoverButton-disable" variant="primary"></b-btn>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
      <b-popover :disabled.sync="disabled" target="popoverButton-disable" title="{{name}}">
        <a>Profile</a> | <a>Logout</a>
      </b-popover>
    </div>
  </div>`
  ,
    data() {
      return {
        disabled: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
       disableByRef() {
           if (this.disabled){
               this.$refs.popover.$emit('enable')
           }else{
               this.$refs.popover.$emit('disable')
           }
       } 
    },
    props: ['name']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `name` to your component by attribute, not by data:

```
<div id="app">
  <setting-template name="Elon" />
</div>
```

Here you can check working example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwrOqY?editors=1111

`data` is component private data - it's not passed to child components.
If you still need `name` in your main component data you can pass it to the child component like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <setting-template :name="name" />
</div>

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        settingTemplate
    },
    data: {
      name: 'Leon'
    }
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLvqeO?editors=1111

Comment: Hi Beniamin, your answer has solved my problem. However, I have another answer I would like to ask. How do I pass the data(component private data) to child components?

Comment: You need to pass each property separately like: `<setting-template :a="a" :b="b" :c="c" />`

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer helped me alot

Comment: or `<setting-template :propsToPass="propsToPass" />` and data: `{ propsToPass: {a: 'a' ...} }`, but separately is much better.